# React Formik - not submitting form

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a simple form with datepicker:

```
export function ReportsFiltersForm() {
  const customerId = useRequiredIntParam('customerId')
  const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  const initialValues = useMemo(() => createDeliveryReportsQueryParams(Object.fromEntries(params)), [params])
  const { push } = useHistory()

  const onSubmit = (values: DeliveryReportsQueryParams) => {
    console.log('submitting ', values)
    push(formatResultsPath(customerId, values))
  }

  return (
    <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} enableReinitialize>
      <>
        <ReportsDashboardFiltersFormFields />
      </>
    </Formik>
  )
}

export function ReportsFiltersFormFields() {
  const { values } = useFormikContext<any>()
  const showCustomDates = values.range === 'custom'

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-2">
      {showCustomDates && <FormikCustomDates />}
      <FormikDateRange options={dateRangeOptions} />
      <FormikSearchButton />
    </div>
  )
}

export function FormikDateRange({ name = 'range', options = dateRangeOptions }: FormikDateRangeProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <FormikSelect name={name} aria-label={i18next.t('date.date')}>
        <FormikSelectOptions options={options as unknown as FormikSelectOption[]} />
      </FormikSelect>
    </div>
  )
}

export function FormikSearchButton(props: { loading?: boolean }) {
  return (
    <ButtonBase type="submit" variant="primary" disabled={props.loading} className="!px-8">
      {i18next.t('button.search')}
    </ButtonBase>
  )
}
```

The problem is when I click on the search button form is not submitting anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise I need to use `Form` tag as well in Formik, so this fixed the problem:

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={onSubmit} enableReinitialize>
  <Form>
    <ReportsDashboardFiltersFormFields />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like adding an onClick to your ButtonBase component:

```
 <ButtonBase type="submit" variant="primary" onClick={onSubmit} disabled={props.loading} className="!px-8">
  {i18next.t('button.search')}
</ButtonBase>
```